# Give two text boxes the same value one is filled in using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have 2 textboxes with a type="number".
1 textbox is my 'master' textbox, then I have another subsequent textbox that I would like that IF the 'master' textbox is filled in with a number, the subsequent textbox would get the same value.

I thought about using the data- attribute but I am not sure how to target if the 'master' textbox is filled then, then subsequently put the same value in the sub textbox(es) with the same data- attribute.

In my example below I also use spans to create plus and minus buttons that adjust the value based on the value. This is in the JS section.

My current HTML is as follow:

```
<div id="masterTextboxes">
    <span class="minusBtn AddMinusButton">-</span>
      <input type="number" value="" placeholder="0" data-attendees="Adult" />
    <span class="addBtn AddMinusButton">+</span>
    <span class="minusBtn AddMinusButton">-</span>
     <input type="number" value="" placeholder="0" data-attendees="Child" />
    <span class="addBtn AddMinusButton">+</span>
</div>

<!--Values from Master Textboxes should populate into these textboxes as well.-->

<div id="subTextboxes">
    <span class="minusBtn AddMinusButton">-</span>
      <input type="number" value="" placeholder="0" data-attendees="Adult" />
    <span class="addBtn AddMinusButton">+</span>
    <span class="minusBtn AddMinusButton">-</span>
     <input type="number" value="" placeholder="0" data-attendees="Child" />
    <span class="addBtn AddMinusButton">+</span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   /*Add an minus buttons for variants*/
$(".AddMinusButton").on('click touchstart', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Add button active style for touch.

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
    var newVal = oldValue;
    //Hide .decButton for oldValue
    if (newVal == 0 || oldValue == 0 ) {
        oldValue = 0;
    }
    else { $button.parent().find(".minusBtn").show(); }
    if ($button.text() == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue >= 1) {
            newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        }
    }

    $button.parent().find("input.attendeeQuantityInput").val(newVal);

   //Sub textboxes should take value of master textboxes. Is this correct syntax?
   //This is probably wrong.
    $('#subTextboxes input').data("attendee").val(newVal);

});//End button click

});
</script>
```

I hope this makes sense on what I am trying to get out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use JQuery? Because using a framework that does data binding (knockout.js, angular.js, etc.) would be much easier.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham. I would love to use Angular.js but right now I am not versed in it.  I just found my answer though using jQuery.  I appreciate the feedback. Angular is on my docket next to learn.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2x141b6y/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

### HTML:

```html
<div id="masterTextboxes">
    <p>Master</p>
      <input type="number" value="" placeholder="0" data-attendees="Adult" />
     <input type="number" value="" placeholder="0" data-attendees="Child" />
</div>
<div id="subTextboxes">
    <p>Sub</p>
      <input type="number" value="" placeholder="0" data-attendees="Adult" />
     <input type="number" value="" placeholder="0" data-attendees="Child" />
</div>
```

### JS:

```
// On change in master inputs...
$("#masterTextboxes input", this).on("change", function() {
    // Store Master inputs in master variable and Sub inputs in sub variable.
    var master = $("#masterTextboxes input"),
        sub = $("#subTextboxes input");
    // Match master and sub values by using the master array key as reference.
    $(sub[$.inArray($(this)[0], master)]).val( $(this).val() );
});
```

The jQuery code relies on the condition that the Sub inputs follow the same order as the Master's inside each respective div.

### JSFiddle:

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/d67vLmuc/) for reference.

Comment: That is a much more elegant option than what I came up with after I  posted this questions. but yes, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like that IF the 'master' textbox is filled in with a number,
>   the subsequent textbox would get the same value.

You can do it like this:

```
<p>
  <label>Master 1: <input type="number" id="master1" placeholder="0" /></label><br>
  <label>Dependant 1: <input type="number" class="dependant1" placeholder="0" /></label>  
</p>
<p>
  <label>Master 2: <input type="number" id="master2" placeholder="0" /></label><br>
  <label>Dependant 2: <input type="number" class="dependant2" placeholder="0" /></label><br>
  <label>Dependant 2: <input type="number" class="dependant2" placeholder="0" /></label>  
</p>
```

And in the JS:

```
$("input[id^='master']").on("change", function(){
  var no = this.id.replace("master", "");
  var selector = ".dependant" + no
  $(selector).val(this.value);                    
});
```

This makes use of jQuery's [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and will work for any number of inputs provided the class names match.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/2geyp12h/)